# mock useSelector of react-redux with jest for test with react testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a component that uses react-redux for state management.

To test quickly I want to mock useSelector, like this:

```
const templates = [
  {
    id: ...,
    name: ...,
    ...
  },
  {
    id: ...,
    name: ...,
    ...
  },
]


jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
  useSelector: jest.fn(),
}));


describe('some awesome description', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    useSelector.mockImplementation(callback => callback(templates));
  });
});
```

But when running the tests, this fails as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ids')

  141 | describe('layouts/TemplatesPanel', () => {
  142 |   beforeEach(() => {
> 143 |     useSelector.mockImplementation(callback => callback(templates));
      |                                                ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd better not mock `useSelector`, mock implementation possibly breaks its function because its function is not only to return a certain state slice. See the `useSelector` [real implementation](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/7.x/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L130), it doesn't just return the `selectedState`.

The recommended way is to create a mock store and provide mock data for it.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export type Template = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};
export type RootState = {
  templates: Template[];
};

export const MyComp = () => {
  const templates = useSelector<RootState>((state) => state.templates);
  console.log('templates: ', templates);
  return <div>MyComp</div>;
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { MyComp, RootState, Template } from '.';

describe('73494842', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const templates: Template[] = [
      { id: '1', name: 'a' },
      { id: '2', name: 'b' },
    ];
    const mockStore = createStore<RootState, any, any, any>((state = { templates }, action) => {
      if (action.type === 'UPATE_NAME') {
        return {
          ...state,
          templates: templates.map((t) => (t.id === action.payload.id ? { ...t, name: action.payload.name } : t)),
        };
      }
      return state;
    });
    render(
      <Provider store={mockStore}>
        <MyComp />
      </Provider>
    );
    mockStore.dispatch({ type: 'UPATE_NAME', payload: { id: '1', name: 'c' } });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  73494842
    ✓ should pass (44 ms)

  console.log
    templates:  [ { id: '1', name: 'a' }, { id: '2', name: 'b' } ]

      at MyComp (stackoverflow/73494842/index.tsx:14:11)

  console.log
    templates:  [ { id: '1', name: 'c' }, { id: '2', name: 'b' } ]

      at MyComp (stackoverflow/73494842/index.tsx:14:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.931 s, estimated 11 s
```

When we dispatch an action later, the `useSelector` hook will subscribe to the changes of the store, it will execute again and get the updated state slice. If you mock it just return a state slice, this feature is not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the callback function inside the `jest.mock` too.

```
useSelector: (callback) => jest.fn(callback)
```