# How to write test case using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testcase, testing-library, jest-fetch-mock

```
 const { UserData, UserSessionComplete } = useSelector((state) => state?.header);
```

How to get this declaration under coverage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mock useSelector of react-redux with jest for test with react testing-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73494842/mock-useselector-of-react-redux-with-jest-for-test-with-react-testing-library)